# How to make a Text which will scroll its content horizontally while content is longer than size in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Honestly, I don't have any code about it.

Besides using 3rd party sdk or dive in using canvas, I can't think of any other idea.

Just a hint will be better than nothing...

It should behavior like a Marquee.

Answer (score 37):

To create and automatically remember ScrollState with default parameters use rememberScrollState.

```
val scroll = rememberScrollState(0)
```

You can add the horizontalScroll modifier to enable scrolling within the `Text`.

```
Text(
            text = "some long text"
            modifier = Modifier.horizontalScroll(scroll)
        )
```

For more [read](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/ScrollState)

Comment: This approach seems to crash for very long texts